# Pulling elements of list based on information in vectors of another dataframe

Tags: r, list, mapply

I have a list (`my.list`) and a data frame (`my.dataframe`). The names of each element within `my.list` are of a sequence and are of the same type as the elements within two variables in `my.dataframe`. I want to pull out elements of the list whose names fall at, within, or just outside the range of the elements of two columns in `my.dataframe`.

```
RNGkind('Mersenne-Twister')
set.seed(1)

#Create my.dataframe
my.letters <- sample(x = sample(LETTERS[1:20], 
                                size = 13, 
                                replace = FALSE), 
                     size = 100, 
                     replace = TRUE)
my.other.letters <- LETTERS[match(my.letters, LETTERS) + 
                        sample(x = 0:5,
                               size = 100, 
                               replace = TRUE)]
my.dataframe <- data.frame(col1 = my.letters, 
                           col2 = my.other.letters)

head(my.dataframe)
  col1 col2
1    D    F
2    C    C
3    O    O
4    A    E
5    T    T
6    D    F
#So here, I'd want to pull out elements within my.list who's names would fall within D 
#and F for the first row, C for the second row, O for the fourth, A and E for the fifth,
#so on and so forth.

#Create my.list
temp.data <- data.frame(a = rnorm(13*20, 10, 1), 
                        b = rep(LETTERS[sample(1:length(LETTERS), 
                                        size = 13, 
                                        replace = FALSE)], 
                                each = 20))
my.list <- split(x = temp.data$a, f = factor(temp.data$b))
```

I've used `mapply()` to try and do this:

```
mega.list <- mapply(function(f, s)my.list[which(LETTERS == f):which(LETTERS == s)], f = my.dataframe$col1, s = my.dataframe$col2)
```

But it only works if `col1`, `col2`, and the names of the elements in `my.list` have all the letters of the alphabet, but they don't. If you look at `mega.list[[98]]`, you've got an empty list because it's looking for names within `my.list` that fall between `T` and `Y`(`my.dataframe[98,]`). Seeing as there isn't a list element whose name is `T`, you get nothing.

```
sort(unique(as.character(my.dataframe$col1))); sort(unique(as.character(my.dataframe$col2))); sort(unique(names(my.list)))
[1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "F" "H" "I" "K" "N" "O" "P" "S" "T"
[1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G" "H" "I" "J" "K" "L" "M" "N" "O" "P" "Q" "R" "S" "T" "U" "V" "X" "Y"
[1] "A" "B" "D" "E" "F" "G" "H" "J" "K" "R" "S" "W" "Z"
```

**Question:** If the exact letter name isn't available within `my.list`, is there a way to select the next closest letter before or after the letters in `col1` or `col2`, respectively? For example, if it tries to look for a letter `N` from `col1`, how could I get it to select `K` instead? Likewise, if it's trying to find `U` from `col2`, how can I get it to look for `W` instead?

Comment: @akrun my bad, in thinking I made the code simpler I had left out vital information. it's been reverted to what it was before my edit.

Comment: @akrun temp.data is a data frame, but it's converted to a list with the code my.list <- split(x = temp.data$a, f = factor(temp.data$b))

Comment: I think you may need a recursive function to go up and down and check until it meets a case where it is not NULL.  What if the previous or next also becomes NULL

Comment: Something like `my.dataframe %>% mutate_all(as.character) %>% mutate(v1 = map(row_number(), ~ {x1 <- my.list[seq(match(col1[.x], LETTERS), match(col2[.x], LETTERS))]; x2 <- if(all(map_lgl(x1, is.null))) my.list[seq(match(col1[.x - 1], LETTERS), match(col2[.x-1], LETTERS))] else x1; if(all(map_lgl(x2, is.null))) my.list[seq(match(col1[.x + 1], LETTERS), match(col2[.x +1], LETTERS))] else x2}))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I had to make an ammendment to the `mapply` function, where the first `which` function looks for all letters and and before `f` and takes the last value (with the `tail` function) and where the last `which` function looks at all the letters at and after it and takes the first one (done with `[1]`).

```
mega.list <- mapply(function(f, s)my.list[tail(which(names(my.list) <= f), n = 1):which(names(my.list) >= s)[1]], f = as.character(my.dataframe$col1), s = as.character(my.dataframe$col2))
```